# How do you pattern split a javascript string for placement into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'd like to take

```
var string1 = '7~~7.5~~8~~8.5~~9~~9.5~~10~~10.5~~11~~11.5~~12~~13~~14';
var string2 = 'Boot~~Casual~~Dual Comfort~~Plain Toe'
```

and make it

```
var string 1 = ['7','7.5','8','8.5','9','9.5','10','10.5','11','11.5','12','13','14'];

var string 2 = ['Boot','Casual','Dual Comfort','Plain Toe']
```

I've tried mapping through it. I also tried using split. I want to be able to do this programatically for strings of any type that follow the pattern in either string 1 or string 2.

Comment: use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: *"I also tried using split."* - And `.split("~~")` didn't work?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you've tried, otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). [You haven't shown any research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split()` method to convert it to array,

```js
var string1 = '7~~7.5~~8~~8.5~~9~~9.5~~10~~10.5~~11~~11.5~~12~~13~~14';
string1 = string1.split('~~');
console.log(string1);
```